# Type-juggling in php: bypass a comparison with non-empty array

Tags: php, ctf, array-comparison

On an CTF for my web-security-class I was able to find following php-code on the server

```
<?php 
        $user = array("user" => "admin");
        $secret = random_bytes(20);
          if (isset($_GET["usr"]) and isset($_GET["pwd"]))  {
            if ($_GET["usr"] == $user) {
              if (! strcmp($_GET["pwd"], $secret)) {
                echo var_dump(scandir($_GET["path"][1]));
              } else {
                echo "Wrong pwd!";
              }
            } else {
              echo "You are so close!";
            }
          }
?>
```

What payload do I have to send in order to bypass the `$_GET["usr"] == $user` comparison?

I tried sending NULL as "%00", also "0" and "1" because I guess that the weak ==-comparison could open up some type-juggling possibilities, but it didn't work.

Comment: http://www.madirish.net/401: _"As you can see the comparison operator does not have any problem with the null byte (\0)"_ - null bytes in strings don't trip `==` up any more.

Comment: I have to say that the example doesn't make much sense. Why would you compare `$_GET['usr']` against an array to begin with? I get that it's an exercise, but testing improbable code isn't particularly useful, imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$user` variable is an array. **GET** data can contain arrays, you can use the right syntax to "bypass" the condition:

```
?usr[user]=admin
```

I don't think you can make use of type juggling here.